# Nim argv equivalent

Tags: arguments, nim-lang

I'm interfacing a C utility with Nim. The C util `main` function expects **argc** and **argv**. I can get argc from `paramCount` but how do I get a C compatible list of args for argv?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv);
```

```
proc main*(argc: cint; argv: cstringArray): cint
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from `paramCount()` there is the function `paramStr()` which
actually gets the argument strings.

If your C program is:

```
int cmain(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  int x;
  for (x=0; x < argc; x++)
    printf("%d: %s\n", x, argv[x]);
}
```

Then your Nim program `test.nim`, needs to convert the values returned by
the repeated `paramStr()` invocations to a compatible `char **`:

```
{.compile: "cmain.c".}
proc cmain(c: cint, a: cstringArray): cint {.importc.}

import os

var nargv =  newSeq[string](paramCount())
var x = 0
while x < paramCount():
   nargv[x] = paramStr(x+1)  # first is program name
   x += 1

var argv: cStringArray = nargv.allocCStringArray()
discard cmain(cint(paramCount()), argv)
argv.deallocCStringArray()
```

Then running `nim c -r test.nim def ghi` gives:

```
0: def
1: ghi
```

(using the `compile` pragma you don't need to make a shared object from your C file, and link against that, but of course that is possible as well)

Comment: Why need

`var argv: cStringArray = nargv.allocCStringArray()`

why nod directly `discard cmain(cint(paramCount()), nargv)`

?

Comment: @itilmemekcantik I haven't been using Nim for several years now and have no idea.

Comment: @itilmemekcantik, you can't pass `seq[string]` to a C program that requires a `char**`, it will blow up with a `SIGSEGV`. But you can allocate a `seq[string]` as a `CStringArray` to do it, as shown in the solution.

Answer (score 6):

You have your seq of strings variable:

```
var data: seq[string] = @["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

And you allocate it before sending it to the C function:

```
var cdata: cstringArray = data.allocCStringArray()
main(5, cdata)
cdata.deallocCStringArray()
```